# How do I put an element into contenteditable mode via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have the following HTML element

```
<p class="story" contenteditable="true">This is a story.</p>
```

Now I want to put the element into edit mode via javascript. I assumed something like the following would work, but it doesn't

```
$('.story').click();
```

How can I manually put this element in edit mode (via javascript or any other way) without the user clicking on the element?

Comment: Found my problem. I was executing $('.story').focus() from inside the browser javascript console. It doesn't work in the console in chrome of firefox. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `focus` instead of `click`:

```
$(".story").focus();
```

Comment: Why doesn't this command work inside the browser javascript console?

Comment: @matt Not entirely sure (it does for me), but it could be that your console wants to keep the focus down there in the console so that you don't keep losing your cursor while you're working in it. The focus is a window-level thing that can only be in one place.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.story').focus(function(){
    $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
});
```

Comment: This does nothing, the attribute is already set to true in the html.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?